# CodeIgniter Appending 'index.php' twice on js and css paths

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter urls appending index.php twice on js and css scripts
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php/index.php/reports/displayperiod

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to you .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```